# PHP Foreach with Smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm trying to make a dropdown list to work in Smarty from PHP, the data of the dropdown is from mysql.

I achieved this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrRXv.png)

But is not working as a dropdown, it displays all data in one section.

This is the code I used below.

PHP

```
<?php
foreach ($options as $multiplier) {
  $option = "<option ";

  if ($multiplier == $results['multiplier']) {
    $option .= "selected=selected ";
  }

  $option .= "value=" . $multiplier . ">" . unesc($multiplier) . "</option>";

  $multi['option'] = $option;
  $multiplier_option[] = $multi;
}
$smarty->assign('multiplier_option', $multiplier_option);
unset($multiplier_option);
```

And HTML.

```
<tr>
  <td align='left' class='header'>{$lang_multiplier}:</td>
  <td align='left' class='lista' colspan='2'><select name='multiplier'>{foreach item=multi from=$multiplier_option}{$multi.option}{/foreach}</select></td>
</tr>
```

I can't figure out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Smarty do the work for you.

The [html_options](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl) function will build the markup for you, just pass in your multipliers array for the values and output, and set the selected multiplier.

```php
$smarty->assign('multipliers', $options);
$smarty->assign('selectedMultiplier', $results['multiplier']);
```

```smarty
<tr>
    <td align='left' class='header'>{$lang_multiplier}:</td>
    <td align='left' class='lista' colspan='2'>
        {html_options name=multiplier values=$multipliers output=$multipliers selected=$selectedMultiplier}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I added what you posted but the dropdown is empty now and does not display any value.

Comment: I had an error - the variable names in the html_options tag were incorrect. See update.

Comment: Same like in the image I posted, all values are showing in one place ex. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and not in a drop down like 1,2,3 etc... alone for each field in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? This should not be this hard. What does your array look like?